# Moving from Firebase to Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I wanna use Firebase as my backend for my RN app.
Can I migrate later from Firebase to Google Cloud?

Or should I directly start with Google Cloud, and create inside of it a Firebase project?

Because I want to start with Firebase, but maybe it would be one day to limited, and then I want to move to Google Cloud

Answer (score 2):

Firebase is part of Google Cloud.  In fact, a Firebase project is also a Google Cloud project.  It doesn't matter where you start.  There is no migration, and you can use both Firebase and Cloud products in the same project at the same time.

You might want to read this post about [the relationship between Firebase and Google Cloud](https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f).